# Detect ANGLE from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, webgl, three.js

I have a WebGL / Three.js game which has an unhelpful shader program linking error when ANGLE is used for providing WebGL. I'd like to display a prominent warning to ANGLE users (but not bug others) already on the homepage as well as display instructions for switching to native OpenGL renderer. I'd also like to automatically disable the offending feature (shadows) if the user does not switch to native GL.

Three.js does not provide a nice way to detect shader failures and I don't know how I could detect ANGLE, so I'm currently thinking of using this approximation:

`IF Windows AND ( Chrome OR Firefox ) THEN displayWarning()`

Any better ideas?

Comment: I know it sucks but for the time being I would (1) try to change your shader to work around the bug (2) Check if Chrome Canary fixes the bug (3) File a bug at http://crbug.com or http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/issues with a *small* reproducible case. Telling users to switch to OpenGL has other bigger problems. Both Firefox and Chrome require DirectX for other things like video acceleration and/or 2D text acceleration so if you tell users to switch to OpenGL your app may run faster but your users well have worse experiences in general. Better to just push to get ANGLE fixed asap.

Comment: @gman I can't / don't want to directly change the shader as it's an internal Three.js material, but as I said I'm going to turn off a feature for some users based on the answers of this question. Producing a _small_ test case is hard  as three.js' shaders are huge and I need at least a temporary work around now. I don't see how using OpenGL for WebGL would prevent the browser from using DirectX for other things. As ANGLE is mainly used because DX9 drivers are more commonly present than OpenGL 2.1 drivers, I'd guess if the user can run my game, any other WebGL content would then be fine too.

Comment: Because you can't mix DirectX and OpenGL easily so if you want to use both accelerated video and accelerated text AND WebGL all of it has to be based on DirectX.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it's working for me .

```
var _IS_ANGLE_ACTIVE = false;
...
...
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {  antialias: true  });
...
...
var ctx = renderer.domElement.getContext("webgl");
if (ctx==null)
    ctx = renderer.domElement.getContext("experimental-webgl");
if (ctx) {
    var h = ctx.getParameter(ctx.ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE);
    _IS_ANGLE_ACTIVE = (h && h.length==2 && h[0]==1 && h[1]==1);
}
```

The variable h return [1,1] if ANGLE is active or something like [1,10] with native GL.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no because the webgl spec tries to remove any specific information about the GPU and so on.

You could try to make a small testcase that detects the specific problem with readpixels and use that as a warning displayer

Comment: Good point about the GPU information. But I'd still think there could be some signals like a presence/non-presence of a specific extension. Writing a small test case might be hard because e.g. I have several AFAIK identical materials, but one of them fails - so potentially the bug only rises its head after I have compiled dozens of shaders or loaded hundred megabytes of textures and I don't want to do that on the homepage.